# How to use / where to find Haskell API?

Tags: haskell

Is this the documentation I should use for learning about the various haskell functions: https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-api/GHC.html ?

Can search from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-api/GHC.html) or other Haskell doc for how each type should be used? For example if I wanted to learn more about the `Int` type (without tying `:t` on command line) can this be searched upon ?

If above is the API it seems much more minimalist that say a Java/Scala API. But perhaps this is one of the strong points of Haskell provide a succinct, yet very powerful set of base functions to build my abstractions upon ?

Comment: Are you wanting to know what functions you can call on an Int? Try looking for Int in hoogle. Then try `:i Int` to see what typeclasses an Int implements, and look for functions that work on those typeclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ghc-api is the API for interacting with the GHC compiler. The "standard library" is documented at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base.

Answer (score 1):

> Can search from here or other Haskell doc for how each type should be
>   used?

In Haskel you usually think *functions first*, i.e. you may want to know what functions are available, what input they accept and what output they produce. This is typically expressed by class constraints ("must be a list of something") and sometimes as concrete types.

If you want to find particular functions, then try [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). If you enter `Prelude` into the search field, you will find `module Prelude` among the answers. You may see the Prelude as the "Haskell API", i.e. the functions which are always available.

Then there is the [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) package, which consists of a number of additional modules (as already pointed out by Rein Henrichs), which are also widely used.

Finally there is all the rest, i.e. special purpose modules. Many of the can also be found on Hoogle.

But frankly, I don't think that "learning the API" is a good way to approach Haskell. This may work in Java, where you're dealing with Classes, Object and Methods all the time.

In Haskell you are at a much higher level of abstaction. In Haskell you may find ways to implement Classes, Objects and Methods as *one* example showcase for a certain abstraction. However, it would not be abvious from reading the API that you can simulate OOP with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hoogle is a Haskell API search engine, which allows you to search many standard Haskell libraries by either function name, or by approximate type signature. The Hoogle manual contains more details, including further details on search queries, how to install Hoogle as a command line application and how to integrate Hoogle with Firefox/Emacs/Vim etc. 
Thanks,
http://www.thecheesyanimation.com/3d-home-interior-design.html